# How to access to some parameters and actions via API

Tags: parameters, camera, histogram, sony

I need help on sony camera api...

To make an application for scientific applications using sony cameras, I need some parameters to perform the necessary calculations:

Distance camera subject: 
In the api documentation, I could not find any parameter that returns the distance (focus point of the lens o other relative data). Is there an event or method that returns that parameter?

histogram: 
I have not found how to view the histogram data. Can I get in any way?

Image exposure: 
When "touchAFPosition" method. Does the image exposure, will be the point of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For distance camera subject and histogram, these are not supported in the Camera API.

Not sure I understand your question with regards to "image exposure".  Can you explain again?